# Why do these two SELECT COUNT(*) with negated WHERE clauses not sum up correctly?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm selecting rows from a table with a where clause but negating the where clause returns more rows than it should.

Given a table with 1000 rows a `select where` returns 600 rows, shouldn't the negated version of that `select where` return 400 rows?

```
select count(*) from trips
```

The trips table has `420444` rows.

I'm selecting all trips that start in the weekend

```
select count(*) from trips
where service_id in
(select service_id from calendar_dates
where date_part('dow', date) in (5, 6))
```

returns `363272`

Running the same query but for trips not started on the weekend

```
select count(*) from trips
where service_id in
(select service_id from calendar_dates
where date_part('dow', date) not in (5, 6))
```

returns `377326`

`363272` + `377326` = `740598` which is way more than `420444`

Does the `count` function act differently when there is a subquery in a where clause involved?

This is done on a database with GTFS data https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/. I can't figure out what I've missed.

Comment: If a `service_id` has 3 lines in `calendar_dates` associated to the date parts (5, 6, 7), it will be counted by both queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not negated.

If you have the same service_id with `dow = 3, 4, 5, 6`, then it will appear in the 2 counts.

The correct negation is

```
select count(*) from trips
where service_id NOT in
(select service_id from calendar_dates
where date_part('dow', date) in (5, 6))
```

Or equivalent with `not exists`